# Create new dataframe based on two other dataframes

Tags: python, dataframe

Actually I'm still new to Python and Pandas and don't know how to go on.

Basic overview: I have to create a location recommendation system. I was given some foursquare data with a `venueID` and `sub(!)categoryID`. But my recommendation should consider all data from the main category. So somehow I must assign the main categories to my venues.

My foursquare dataframe looks like this:

```
UserID  VenueID CategoryID  CategoryName    
470 49bbd6c0f964a520f4531fe3    4bf58dd8d48988d127951735    Arts & Crafts Store 
979 4a43c0aef964a520c6a61fe3    4bf58dd8d48988d1df941735    Bridge  
69  4c5cc7b485a1e21e00d35711    4bf58dd8d48988d103941735    Home (private)
```

I already have created a dataframe with the main categories and their subcategories:

```
 Main Category Name          Main Category ID         Sub Categories Name         Sub Categories ID
0    Arts & Entertainment  4d4b7104d754a06370d81259                Amphitheater  56aa371be4b08b9a8d5734db
1    Arts & Entertainment  4d4b7104d754a06370d81259                    Aquarium  4fceea171983d5d06c3e9823
2    Arts & Entertainment  4d4b7104d754a06370d81259                      Arcade  4bf58dd8d48988d1e1931735
```

So basically I want to: if `VenueID's Category ID` (from foursquare df) is in `categories_df` then write `venueID` with corresponding main `category ID` in a new dataframe. I hope you unterstand what I mean.

In the end I just want to use the main categories for my recommendation and not consider the sub categories.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout [pandas.DataFrame.merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df_foursquare.merge(df_categories, how='left', left_on=['CategoryID'], right_on=['Sub Categories ID'])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems this is exactly what I wanted. I already had to think all the time of SQL and how I would do it with SQL ... ^^